# How to make POST request with __RequestVerificationToken header in Postman

Tags: api, post, http-post, postman

I want to send a POST request with Postman to receive back information from a database with a list of elements.

**Case:**

1. On a Home page, I have a search engine when I'm choosing parameters. **URL://example.com**
2. I'm clicking button: Display on a list **URL://example.com**
3. I'm receiving list with searched elements **URL://example.com/Search/Result**

## Fist Test

Method: Post

URL: example.com

Headers: Content-Type - application/json

Temporary Headers: which include :  __RequestVerificationToken

**Body:**

```
{
"options": "1",
"IsMember": "false",
"ID": "2",
"btnShowList" : "true"
}
```

**Result:**
Status: 200,
But in a body I have HTML of whole home page, so probably post was not executed

## Second Test

Method: Post

URL: example.com/Search/Result

Headers: Content-Type - application/json

Temporary Headers: which include :  __RequestVerificationToken

**Body:**

```
{
"options": "1",
"IsMember": "false",
"ID": "2",
"btnShowList" : "true"
}
```

**Result:**
Status: 404, Not Found

## Questions:

Is it possible to do the post if in URL is no query parameres?

Any idea how can I write such a test case?

Have anyone writes post method with dynamic parameters such as eg. __RequestVerificationToken

Answer (score 0):

Receiving an HTML in response is totally normal, especially if the technology used is ASP.net WebForms for instance.
To answer some of your questions: It is possible to make a post with no query params. All you need to do is hit the correct url with the expected body